# Как получить номер недели?

Tags: c#

Нужно получить номер недели. С первой неделей года всё понятно. А если первая неделя будет текущая (26.03 - 01.04) с учётом високосного года. Т.е. предыдущая неделя (19.03 - 25.03) была 52?

Answer (score 6):

Считать недели можно по-разному. Можно считать первой неделю, в которой первое января. Можно считать первой неделю, в которой первый понедельник года. Можно считать первой неделю, бóльшая часть которой принадлежит новому году. Как именно считать — выбирать вам. В .NET за этот выбор отвечает энумерация [`System.Globalization.CalendarWeekRule`](https://docs.microsoft.com/ru-ru/dotnet/api/system.globalization.calendarweekrule?view=netframework-4.7).

Получить номер недели по дате можно так:

```
var dt = new DateTime(2017, 1, 1);
var cal = new GregorianCalendar();
var weekNumber = cal.GetWeekOfYear(dt, CalendarWeekRule.FirstFullWeek, DayOfWeek.Monday);
// получается 52
```

Мы видим, что по правилу «год начинается с полной недели» 1 января 2017 года принадлежит 52-ой неделе прошлого, 2016 года.

Comment: но 2019 показывает как високосный с 53 неделями.

Comment: @Just_Deniss: Это как? Покажите ваш код, что он выдаёт (и почему из этого следует високосность 2019 года).

Comment: private void numericUpDown1_ValueChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            var dt = new DateTime(Convert.ToInt32(numericUpDown1.Value), 1, 1);
            var cal = new GregorianCalendar();
           var weekNumber = cal.GetWeekOfYear(dt, CalendarWeekRule.FirstFullWeek, DayOfWeek.Monday);
          label1.Text = weekNumber.ToString();
        } 2018, 2024,  2029 ... показывает только 1 неделю, 2019, 2025,  2030 показывает 53

Comment: @Just_Deniss: Ну да, всё правильно, так и надо.

Answer (score 2):

Не знаю, правильно ли понял, что вы хотите сделать, но допустим:

У вас есть объект `DateTime`. Не знаю, как вы его получите, будь то `DateTime.Now`, `DateTime.UtcNow`, или как-то еще. Задача в определении того, какая по счету неделя идет для этой даты.

Тогда задача становится тривиальной:

```
DateTime myDateTime = DateTime.Now;
int firstDayOfYear = (int)new DateTime(myDateTime.Year, 1, 1).DayOfWeek;
int weekNumber = (myDateTime.DayOfYear + firstDayOfYear) / 7;
```

Тогда переменная `weekNumber` будет хранить значение, и при этом первая неделя будет `0`, вторая - `1` и т.д. Если нужно считать недели, начиная с `1`, то просто

```
int weekNumber = (myDateTime.DayOfYear + firstDayOfYear) / 7 + 1;
```

Как-то так.

Comment: Нет, не так. Ваша неделя начинается с любого дня?

Comment: @Igor ну конкретики в вопросе тоже было не много, но да, сейчас исправлю

Comment: а какой конкретики вам не хватает? может её стоит уточнить у автора?

Comment: @Igor вот, кажется так

Comment: @tym32167 ну, промежуток `19.03 - 25.03` - неделя от пн до вс, так что думаю, косяк был все же мой. Я поправил, так верно, кажется

Comment: @selya Мне нравится ваш пример, но как его переделать чтобы первая неделя приходилась на (26.03.2018 - 01.04.2018)?

Comment: Если вы хотите сделать так, чтобы неделя начиналась не с воскресенья, то сделайте таблицу дней недели. Зная, что `DayOfWeek` возвращает `0` для воскресенья, можно сделать таблицу вида: `int[] days = new int[] { 6, 0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5 };` Далее в коде заменяем `DayOfWeek` на `days[...DayOfWeek]`. Смысл в том чтобы сместить значения дня недели. Надеюсь, смысл понятен. Думаю, вы разберетесь. (По сути, можно добавить третью строчку `firstDayOfYear = days[firstDayOfYear]`)

Comment: @Just_Deniss а, кажется, не совсем верно вас понял. Тут уже нужно подстраиваться под конкретную задачу. К вечеру освобожусь, может помогу с этим

Answer (score 1):

В netstandard2.1 (.NET Core 3.0) появился класс [ISOWeek](https://docs.microsoft.com/ru-RU/dotnet/api/system.globalization.isoweek?view=netstandard-2.1) который рассчитывает неделю по стандарту ISO8601, рекомендую использовать его:

Дата -> номер недели:

```
var week = ISOWeek.GetWeekOfYear(dt);
```

Номер недели -> дата:

```
var dt = ISOWeek.ToDateTime(year, week, DayOfWeek.Monday);
```

PS Определение ISO 8601 для недели 01 - это неделя с первым четвергом григорианского года.

Answer (score 0):

Так будет работать актуально!

```
var dt = new DateTime(2017, 1, 1);
var cal = new GregorianCalendar();
var weekNumber = cal.GetWeekOfYear(dt, CalendarWeekRule.FirstFourDayWeek,DayOfWeek.Monday);
```